# Same behavior as ActionLink from javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I would like to update the content of a div using the result from  an action method which returns a PartialView.

The below code would do just this.

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "Comments", new { id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divComments" })%>

<div id="divComments" />

public ActionResult Comments(string id)
    {
        ...
        return View(photo.Comments);
    }
```

Is it possible to have this update occur from inside a javascript method rather than from a link on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are familiar with jQuery, just use $.ajax() or $.load() methods.

Comment: Thanks I used this in a javascript function if anyone is interested.     
$('#divComments').load('/Photo/Comments/1',
                function (html) {
                    $('#divComments')[0].value = html;
                }
            );

Comment: you did not even need `, function (html) { $('#divComments')[0].value = html; }` part, unless you have several `#divComments` on your page.